# *** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a function that does this : 
func [3,3,5,7] 1 = [(3,2),(5,1),(7,1)]
It makes tuple of unique elements in a list and gives the occurence of the elements. I wrote this :

```
func [] n = []
func (x:xs) n = if x == head xs then func (xs) (n + 1) else (x, n) : func (xs) 1
```

I get this exception :

> *** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list

In order to fix this I write this :

```
func [] n = []
func [x] n = (x,n)
func (x:xs) n = if x == head xs then func (xs) (n + 1) else (x, n) : func (xs) 1
```

But now I get this error :

> Couldn't match expected type `[a0]' with actual type`(t0, t1)' In the
>   expression: (x, n) In an equation for func: func [x] n = (x, n)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first problem is here:

```
func (x:xs) n = if x == head xs ...
```

`xs` can be the empty list. You need to make sure `xs` is not empty before taking the head of it.

The second problem is here:

```
func [] n = []
func [x] n = (x,n)
```

In the first line you are saying the return type of `func` is a list, but in the second line you are saying it is a tuple - hence the type error.

What you want is very close to the `group` function in `Data.List` - that can give you some ideas on how to write it.

Alternatively, here is some guidance.

Clearly:

```
func [] = []
```

For the recursion case, try this:

```
func (x:xs) = (x, n) : func rest
  where (n,rest) = ... (some function of x and xs) ...
```

That is, write another function which returns the count and the remainder of the list that `func` has to process.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is in the second case, where you return a tuple instead of a list. Wrapping that tuple in a list solves your type error.

```
func :: Eq a => [a] -> Integer -> [(a, Integer)]
func []           _ = []
func [x]          n = [(x,n)]
func (x:xs@(y:_)) n = if x == y
                      then func xs (n + 1)
                      else (x,n) : func xs 1
```

Comment: You might have spotted this faster if you had written the type signature for your function--it's a good discipline.